# Navigate through a stack of locations in vim?

Tags: vim

Typing <kbd>``</kbd> at location X brings you back to the last visited location in the text file. Hitting it again brings you back to X

This switching is similar to <kbd>Ctrl+6</kbd> to open the last opened file.

But how do can I hop several levels of locations backwards (and then forward)?

I mean something like the <kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> feature for navigate through the stack of visited tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While in command-mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> jump through a stack of locations that you've visited.